# Query Mysql Error : Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, join, unique, alias

Can you please help me out. I have this SQL query:

```
select tenagapengajars.id, tenagapengajars.nama, tenagapengajars.pendidikan, tenagapengajars.created_at, programstudis.nama
    from tenagapengajars
    LEFT JOIN
        tenagapengajars
    ON programstudis.id = tenagapengajars.id_prodi
```

And somehow it says

> #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tenagapengajars'

Comment: If you join the same table again then you need to give these tables different names to distinguish them. And BTW you use a table that you don't even join.

Comment: ok.. sorry my fault..

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting tenagapengajars and also joining on tenagapengajars. If you want to do that, you have to specify an alias. Otherwise MySQL doesn't know chich table you mean.

```
from tenagapengajars t1
LEFT JOIN
tenagapengajars t2
```

You are also selecting data from programstudis, which is not in the query. You probably just copied the wrong table and meant something like:

```
select tenagapengajars.id, tenagapengajars.nama, tenagapengajars.pendidikan,         tenagapengajars.created_at, programstudis.nama
from tenagapengajars
LEFT JOIN
    programstudis
ON programstudis.id = tenagapengajars.id_prodi
```